# ASP MVC 3 Base controller for entity context access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, entity, savechanges, updatemodel

I've implemented a base controller for my MVC 3 project to allow a common way of accessing a user entity from my db context :

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected DBEntitiesContainer db;

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        this.db = new DBEntitiesContainer();
    }

    public UserDetails GetActiveUserDetails()
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = GetObjects.GetActiveUserDetails(this.db);
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

This works great and all my controllers have access to `this.db.MyEntity` and can retrieve a `UserDetails` object by calling `this.GetActiveUserDetails()`

However, the problem arises when I try to perform an update on the entity thus :

```
public class UpdateController : MyBaseController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    UserDetails userDetails = this.GetActiveUserDetails();    
    userDetails.LastOnline = DateTime.Now;
    UpdateModel(userDetails);
    this.db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Any ideas why the `UserDetails` object is easily retrieved, but when I check my database after calling `SaveChanges()`, nothing has been updated ? I'm presuming I'm accessing my context in two different ways, but I can't see how I am...!

Edit: Here's the GetObjects.GetActiveUserDetails() method

```
public static UserDetails GetActiveUserDetails(DBEntitiesContainer db)
{
  MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();    
  UserDetails userDetails;

  try
  {
    if (membershipUser != null)
    {
      userDetails = (from u in db.UserDetails
                     where (u.UserId == (System.Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey)
                     select u).First();
    }
    else
    {
      return GetGuestAccount();
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    return GetGuestAccount();
  }

  return userDetails;
}
```

Not the cleanest method I know...

Comment: Can you show the method body of `GetObjects.GetActiveUserDetails(this.db)`?

Answer (score 1):

UpdateModel is helper method for Controller base class. it supports updating the properties of an object we pass it using the incoming form parameters during HttpPost action method.

It uses relfection to find out the property names of the object (Model object what we passed) and then automatically converts the assigns values to them based on the input values submitted by the form ( client form).

In your case you when u use update model it has no input value find associated model and it make the model default values as it is in database.

try to comment the updatemodel line and runt he code... it must work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to setup data access this way.  One reason is that you should dispose of the db context after you use it.  This means that using your method, this leaves the database connection open until garbage collection occurs, which could be minutes or hours later.  As other web requests come in, new database connections are created, and again those are not disposed of either.. etc.. etc.. it's a pseudo-memory leak (not a true memory leak because it will eventually get collected, but it means resources are being used well after they are needed)